# Error aparentemente inexistente en python con pygame

Tags: python, pygame, fuentes

Tengo un metodo que me convierte una clase "pygame.Font" en una superficie "pygame.Surface" con el método ya predefinido por pygame en la clase "pygame.Font": .render(). El problema esta en que algunas veces, sin sentido aparente el programa se me queda congelado y al cabo de unos pocos segundos, se cierra la pestaña de pygame y el programa de python acaba.
El código con el que hago esto es el siguiente:

```
self.font = pygame.font.Font(self.fontString, self.size)
```

.
.
.

```
def createRenderizable(self):
    self.textSurface = self.font.render(self.text, self.antialias, self.color, self.backgroundColor)
```

Todo esto dentro de una clase.

No puedo poner ningún error por que no me da ninguno, solo se me cierra el programa despues de unos pocos segundos.

Creo que puede ser por algo de los threads de pygame, pero no estoy seguro y no se como solucionarlo.

Pos si les es útil, la pagina oficial de pygame donde viene el método .render() y la clase Font: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render

Comment: Y estás seguro que en esas lineas es donde está el error? intentaste debugear? hacer algo como ir comentado trozos de código para descubrir el problema, o ir linea por linea en la ejecución para ver donde se cae

Comment: Si, estoy seguro, por que puse print(x) delante de cada linea de donde podia estar el error, y el ultimo print(x) que me ejecuto fue el que estaba deante de la llamada al metodo createRenderizable(). (x iba variando para cada linea, para saber en que linea habia fallado.